# How to conditionally run OnSuccess

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this Ajax call.  If the user successfully logs in, I want to run OnSuccess().  But if not, don't run it.

Right now, it always runs because the Ajax call hasn't really failed.  It succeeded as far as making the call was concerned, but the user is not actually logged in so I don't want to run it yet..

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessDownloadLogin", "Order", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "content", OnFailure = "openErrorWindow()", OnSuccess= "getReport()" }))
    {...
```

So how do I conditionally run OnSuccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use OnSuccess to determine behavior like this. OnSuccess should only determine if the Ajax call was successful. You want to keep this logic. Otherwise you are creating a hack that will be hard to maintain and work on for later developers or yourself. Pass back a JSON result that has some flag set if they are not logged in. That way you can handle any situation as new circumstances come up. Fox example:

On Server:

```
Public JsonResult SomeMethod()

// some code here

return Json({loggeddIn: true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And Client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/SomeController/SomeMethod",
    type: "POST",
    data: parameters,
    success: function(result)
{ If (result.loggedIn == true) { 
 //Do logged in code
 }
 Else {
  // do code for not logged in users... like redirect them to login page
 } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the status code of the response to something like 401 Unauthorized then you will be able to call OnFailure.

Alternatively if you don't want the request to fail just change the status code to something like 204 No Content and check the status code in your OnSuccess function.